# If a weakly null sequence has a convergent subsequence, then the original sequence converges.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose that a weakly null sequence $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ has a convergent subsequence in $X$. Does this imply the convergence of the series?

My idea: Let $x_n \to 0$ in $\sigma(X, X')$ and $x_{n_k} \to 0$ in $X$. If $(x_n)$ is not norm null, exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb n$, exists $N_n$ with $\| x_{N_n} \| > \epsilon.$ By the other side, exists $k_0$ such that $\|x_{n_k}\| < \epsilon$ for all $k \geq k_0$. Applying Hahn-Banach, we can find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $X'$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ such that $ |f_k(x_{N_{n_k}})| > \epsilon$.

Well, I can't proceed from this in a way to get a contradiction.

Help?

Comment: In $\ell^2$ the sequence $e_1,0,e_2,0,e_3,0,...$ converges weakly to $0$. It has the convergent subsequence $0,0,...$, but the sequence itself doesn't converge to $0$ since $\|e_i\|=1$.

Comment: Oh, you said 'series'? As in $\sum x_i$?